# Replace gapply function with other code in SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

How can I replace the `gapply` function in SparkR? I want to aggregate some data and apply a function to the aggregate data and I don't want a collect() function, the data don't come back to driver machine.

I have a `DatraFrame` Spark:

```
       CNPJ              PID              DATA     N
 23104577000149   7898586660649     2016-02-01     2
 23104577000149   7898132542078     2016-02-01     2
 11660954000147   7898944830295     2016-02-01     2
 10140281000131   7896496920747     2016-02-01     1
 23104577000149   7891772150900     2016-02-01     1
 10140281000131   789895720413854   2016-01-31     1
```

and I want to aggregate for CNPJ and PID fields.

like this:

```
schema <- structType(structField("CNPJ", "string"),
               structField("PID", "string"),
               structField("DATA", "date"), 
               structField("N", "double"))

result <- gapply(
    ds_filtered,
    c("CNPJ", "PID"),
    function(key, x)
    { 
     dts <- data.frame(key, DATA = seq(min(as.Date(x$DATA)), as.Date(e_date), "days")) 
     colnames(dts)[c(1, 2)] <- c("CNPJ", "PID") 
     y <- data.frame(key, DATA = as.Date(x$DATA), N = x$N) 
     colnames(y)[c(1, 2)] <- c("CNPJ", "PID") 
     y <- dplyr::left_join(dts, y, by = c("CNPJ", "PID", "DATA")) 
     y[is.na(y$N), 4] <- 0 
     data.frame(CNPJ = as.character(y$CNPJ), 
                PID = as.character(y$PID), 
                DATA = as.Date(y$DATA), 
                N = y$N) 
   },
   schema
)
```

In my `gapply`, I am filling in the column DATA with dates (type Date). Then I fill in the missing dates with zeros.

The `gapply` doesn't work in Databricks environment (ore in: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19711).

So, I can't use `gapply`. :-(

Thank you!

Comment: Hello zero323!! I edited my question with one example. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Add StringsAsFactor = FALSE in dataframe returned from gapplay()